how to fix app login access from myapp and restrict from other users in azure
I have problem when create external identity & azure ad b2c, to create access management login, i have create azure ad b2c, app registration & add app launcher at enterprice application.
Users can access apps from myapp when administrator invite external user, and user get invitation code via email.
But other user still can access the application when copy the url link and paste it to browser.
How to restrict url link from other users without invitation.
Thanks.
I have create app management use external identity, Azure AD B2C, App registration, user flow and app launcher
After invite external user from entra id, users get email invitation link to verified and go to myapp dashboard, and found the app link.
user can access it.
but the url can be access from other user by copying and pasting to browser.
